# firebase snapshot.val() returns null

Tags: firebase, react-native

I'm trying to get user information from Firebase database, but it always returns null.

export const employeesFetch = () => {
    const { currentUser } = firebase.auth();

```
return (dispatch) => {
    firebase.database().ref(`/users/${currentUser.uid}/employees`)
        .on('value', snapshot => {

            console.log("snapshot: ", snapshot.val()) // null
            dispatch({ type: EMPLOYEE_FETCH_SUCCESS, payload: snapshot.val() });
        });
};
```

};

Comment: Can you confirm do you send correct `uid` and this id is existing on your firebase Database

Comment: yes I am sending the correct  `uid`

Comment: Can you try to set, just to verify the on `value` works correctly. Add these code behind your code


firebase.database().ref(`/users/${currentUser.uid}/employees`).set([])

Comment: Thank you I wrote the ref value wrong. `firebase.database().ref(/users/${currentUser.uid}/employess)`

Comment: Great. you're welcome

Answer (score 0):

If you use numeric IDs for an array of objects, then **it will fill in missing items with a null.** For example if you don't have an element `0` then your first item will be null.

```
{
  "myList" : [ null, null, {
    "myProp" : "thing",
    "created" : 1582242432,
  }, {
    "myProp" : "another",
    "created" : 1582242555,
  }
}
```

[Why do firebase collections seem to begin with a null row?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15534917/)

Answer (score 0):

> According to the documentation, val() returns null when there's no data at the location of the query:
>
> Depending on the data in a DataSnapshot, the val() method may return a scalar type (string, number, or boolean), an array, or an object. It may also return null, indicating that the DataSnapshot is
>   empty (contains no data).
>
> The internal contents of the DataSnapshot object are not to be used directly. Use the public API instead.