# Cannot read property of 'messages' of undefined

Tags: javascript, reactjs, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

I have a listener for changes in a Firebase DB. Messages write to Firebase, but whenever I try to update local state via the listener, it returns `Cannot read property 'messages' of undefined`.

Error in the Code

Line 122-125 of App.js

Github: https://github.com/kingdomwilks/Slack2

Error Message:

> Cannot read property 'messages' of undefined.

I have console logged the object being returned by the listener & it seems to be an array.

FIREBASE LISTENER

```
firebasePeopleListener = () => {
    database().ref('people/').on('value', (snapshot) => {
        let people = snapshot.val();
        console.log(people);
        this.setState({
            people: people
        });
    });
}
```

ERROR appearing here

```
render() {
console.log(this.state);
let messages = [];
let isSomethingSelected = false;

if(this.state.selectedPersonId) {
    messages = this.state.people[this.state.selectedPersonId - 1].messages;
    isSomethingSelected = true;
}
```

Comment: Can you provide a sample of what you have when you do console.log(people)?

Comment: What is `selectedPersonId`? I'll take a guess and say it's the person's ID. What is `this.state.people`? I'll guess an array. Is `selectedPersonId` an array index value or the actual ID of the person? Because it looks to me like you're treating it like an index (assuming `people` is an array).

Comment: check that you have a value at `selectedPersonId - 1` index in the people array of the component's state. The error says that there is nothing there.

Comment: why you are doing `this.state.people[this.state.selectedPersonId - 1]` means `-1`, because if you are doing -1 it means to get a message from some other persons's object. which is not correct. like if you have 0th id of person then -1 will be `-1` id which doesn't exists. so please remove -1

Answer (score 0):

The `people` array returned from your database is returning the people list with the first value as `empty`, so when you try to access `this.state.people[0]`, it won't find anything there and it will throw the error.

[image]

There seems to be a discussion [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15534917/why-do-firebase-collections-seem-to-begin-with-a-null-row) as to why Firebase collections seem to begin with a null row.

However, you can make a change in your `firebasePeopleListener` in `App.js` and filter out the response to only add to the state people that have an `id` set.

```
firebasePeopleListener = () => {
        database().ref('people/').on('value', (snapshot) => {
            let people = snapshot.val();
            let updatedPeople = [];

            for(let i in people) {
                if(people.hasOwnProperty(i) && people[i].id) {
                    updatedPeople.push(people[i]);
                }
            }
            this.setState({
                people: updatedPeople
            });
        });
    };
```

This should fix your problem for now.